# Fixed Footer showing scrollbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to eliminate the scroll from left to right. When I toggle my sidebar, it closes goes away *(at least on firefox, still shows on IE)* however, when I have it open it shows, I'm not sure why.

**Here is the CodePen -** https://codepen.io/jamiebrs/pen/zJBLWZ

I think it has something to do with my use of bootstrap columns like this.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-2"><a href="#">Back</a></div>
<div class="col-lg-auto"><input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:80%"/></div>
</div>
```

Comment: One way is by changing the left menu position to Fixed , and adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the offending CSS is:

```
#page-content-wrapper {
    padding: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Changing the `width` property to `auto` (or just removing it) fixes it.

Comment: That does remove it when the Sidebar is toggled open, but when it is toggled closed it comes back.

Comment: You need to update the "toggled" CSS rule as well, in that case: `#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper` should include `width: 100%;`.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you.